# Java iterator stuff

Tags: java, iterator

```
public class Show {
    public static ArrayList Ara = new ArrayList();
    public static Iterator snake;

    public static void kai(){
        Ara.add(1);
        Ara.add(2);
        Ara.add(5);
        Ara.add(7);
        Ara.add(10);
        Ara.add(13);        
        snake = Ara.iterator();
        while(snake.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(snake.next());
            if(snake.next()==7)break;
        }
    }       

    public static void main(String[] args){
        kai();
    }
}
```

At execution, 1, 5, 10 consecutively prints out. How do I explain this? I expected 1, 2, 5 would print out instead.

Comment: you r calling .next multiple times (twice)

Comment: Please change your title to something more descriptive.

Comment: `snake.next()` advances the iterator to the next element.

Comment: Try assigning `snake.next()` to a separate variable like `int i = snake.next();`

Answer (score 2):

You should change the code like the following:

```
public static void kai(){
    Ara.add(1);
    Ara.add(2);
    Ara.add(5);
    Ara.add(7);
    Ara.add(10);
    Ara.add(13);        
    snake = Ara.iterator();
    while(snake.hasNext()){
        int value = (int) snake.next();
        System.out.println(value );
        if(value ==7)break;
    }
}
```

That way you only call `iterator.next()` one time inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `Iterator.next()` multiple times (twice) inside the while loop
... that is the reason that explains the behav...

Your list has this elements: **1,2,5,7,10 and 13**
and this line `System.out.println(snake.next());` **discards** and prints the element 1,5,10

BTW the list is raw in your example, so I can imagine, the condition snake.nect()==7 is never met and therefore not breaking the loop

I didn't try to hard to fix it, in fact code is not compiling because of an 
**Incompatible operand types Object and int**
if you code properly the collection (not using raw)
then you will need to do something like

```
 if (((Integer) snake.next()).intValue() == 7)
```

Comment: ok, but that doesn't explain why did 10 print out, right? I do understand why 1 prints out, 2 is skipped, and 5 prints out. But then the call to snake.next() would return a 7, and the loop execution should stop.